# Windows Azure Connection String

Tags: connection-string, azure-storage

probably a simple question here but here we go:

I'm trying to publish a sample application to windows azure. I entered the connection string for my blob storage account in the ServiceConfiguration and Service Definition files.

However, if I check out the properties of the web role, in 'Settings', my connection string has changed to a 'String' type, and there is a red exclamation mark which says

> "the Storage account credentials entered are invalid"

Obviously this error is self explanatory - however I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Here is my connection string - if someone could take a look and ensure it is right, I'd be grateful.

```
<Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocal=http;AccountName=userdevelopment;AccountKey=accKey" />

<Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocal=http;AccountName=userdevelopment;AccountKey=accKey" />
```

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is my ServiceDef file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SilverlightUpload" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="SilverlightUpload_WebRole">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="DataConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you misspelled "protocol"? (I see "protocal" in your configuration.)

Also, just FYI, you said you pasted ServiceConfiguration.cscfg, but it sure looks like ServiceDefinition.csdef.